# DateTime.Now - first and last minutes of the day

Tags: c#, datetime

Is there any easy way to get a `DateTime`'s "`TimeMin`" and "`TimeMax`"?

`TimeMin`: The very first moment of the day. There is no `DateTime` that occurs *before* this one and still occurs on the same day.

`TimeMax`: The very last moment of the day. There is no `DateTime` that occurs *after* this one and still occurs on the same day.

These values would be helpful for filtering and doing date-related queries.

Comment: You mean 00:00:00.000 and 23:59:59.999 ?

Comment: Trying to prep your software so it will be usable on Mars some day?

Comment: What do "TimeMin" and "TimeMax" mean? Exactly?

Comment: It's something that's helpful for filtering and doing date-related queries

Comment: Minor problem with the wording. DateTime.Now is (more or less) precisely *now*. Its min time is *now*. Its max time is *now*. What you want is the minimum and maximum time of a given *day*, not a given *now*.

Comment: @Mark its about getting the value of midnight

Comment: Today's date, but at the beginning of the day is easy: `DateTime.Today`.

Comment: @Fosco technically the DateTime object stores ticks which contains a higher fidelity than milliseconds as well but i agree these are known values that can be made constants if necessary.

Comment: See this post [How to get the start and end times of a day](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/902789/how-to-get-the-start-and-and-end-times-of-a-day/28863401#28863401)

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Here are two extensions I use to do exactly that.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the 12:00:00 instance of a DateTime
    /// </summary>
    public static DateTime AbsoluteStart(this DateTime dateTime)
    {
        return dateTime.Date;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the 11:59:59 instance of a DateTime
    /// </summary>
    public static DateTime AbsoluteEnd(this DateTime dateTime)
    {
        return AbsoluteStart(dateTime).AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1);
    }
```

This allows you to write:

```
DateTime.Now.AbsoluteEnd() || DateTime.Now.AbsoluteStart()
```

or

```
DateTime partyTime = new DateTime(1999, 12, 31);

Console.WriteLine("Start := " + partyTime.AbsoluteStart().ToString());
Console.WriteLine("End := " + partyTime.AbsoluteEnd().ToString());
```

Comment: AbsoluteStart can be relaced with DateTime.Now.Date

Comment: `DateTime.Now.AbsoluteStart()` is redundant, as it'd be identical to `DateTime.Today`.  `DateTime.Today` is "An object that is set to today's date, with the time component set to 00:00:00." -- MSDN

Comment: we don't always want Today

Comment: I like this the best although I might suggest changing return AbsoluteStart(dateTime).AddDays(1).AddMilliseconds(-1); with return AbsoluteStart(dateTime).AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1); as unlikely as it is you could still get a DateTime that is between 23:59:59.999 and 00:00:00.000 the next day since DateTime goes down to a Ticks fidelity.

Comment: @Mark, that example was just an example, it could be any DateTime.

Comment: It's party time! P-A-R-T-Why? Because, I gottttta!

Comment: if DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("11/5/2014 10:10 PM"); then does AbsoluteEnd gives max value of 11/5/2014. I think it should be like `return AbsoluteStart(dateTime).Date.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1);`

Comment: `AbsoluteStart(dateTime) == dateTime.Date`

Comment: Be aware not to inadvertently call AbsoluteEnd on a DateTime.MaxValue. This will throw an ArgumentOutOfRangeException. An alternative is to add ticks instead: AbsoluteStart(dateTime).AddTicks(863999999999)

Answer (score 14):

I'd use the following:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime startOfDay = now.Date;
DateTime endOfDay = startOfDay.AddDays(1);
```

and use `< endOfDay` instead of `<= endOfDay`. This will mean that it will work regardless of whether the precision is minutes, seconds, milliseconds, ticks, or something else. This will prevent bugs like [the one we had on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38526/midnight-comment-doesnt-belong-to-either-day/) (though the advice was [ignored](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38526/midnight-comment-doesnt-belong-to-either-day/51731#51731)).

Note that it is important to only call `DateTime.Now` once if you want the start and end of the same day.

Comment: I think the point is to get a date at its first and last moments, not always for calculation, but primarily for calculation

Answer (score 11):

try

```
//midnight this morning
DateTime timeMin = DateTime.Now.Date; 
//one tick before midnight tonight
DateTime timeMax = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1)
```

If you are using this for filtering, as your comments suggest, it is probably a good idea to save DateTime.Now into a variable, just in case the date ticks over between the two calls. Very unlikely but call it enough times and it will inevitably happen one day (night rather).

```
DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
DateTime timeMin = currentDateTime.Date; 
DateTime timeMax = currentDateTime.Date.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1)
```

Comment: It will invariably happen *two* days, as it turns out.

Answer (score 3):

One small tweak to hunter's solution above...
I use the following extension method to get the end of the day:

```
public static DateTime EndOfDay(this DateTime input) {
    return input.Date == DateTime.MinValue.Date ? input.Date.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1) : input.Date.AddTicks(-1).AddDays(1);
}
```

This should handle cases where the DateTime is either `DateTime.MinValue` or `DateTime.MaxValue`. If you call AddDays(1) on DateTime.MaxValue, you will get an exception. Similarly, calling AddTicks(-1) on `DateTime.MinValue` will also throw an exception.

Answer (score 2):

You must be careful to use

```
(new DateTime()).AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1);
```

when it is passed to stored procedure.

It could happen that the value will be approximated to next day.

Answer (score 1):

Like other answerers, I'm not quite sure what you're asking for, but incase you want the smallest possible time and the largest possible time, (not just in a day), then there's `DateTime.MinValue` and `DateTime.MaxValue` which return 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
 and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM respectively.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise that you look at this answer:
[How can I specify the latest time of day with DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821445/how-can-i-specify-the-latest-time-of-day-with-datetime)

If your original DateTimes also potentially include times, using the AddDays() method will add a full 24 hours, which may not be precisely what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static DateTime ToEndOfDay(this DateTime time)
    {
        var endOfDaySpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1).Subtract(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1));
        return time.Date.Add(endOfDaySpan);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note that if you're passing this time to sql server you should use

```
dateTime.Date.AddDays(1).AddMilliseconds(-3);
```

See:

[How do I get the last possible time of a particular day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167316/how-do-i-get-the-last-possible-time-of-a-particular-day)

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1);
```

Not very exact, but fixed my problems. Now we can use AddMilliseconds, AddTicks and etc. I think it will just vary on what would satisfy your need.