# How to not allow user to register more then once a day?

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql

I'm creating a small service where the users log "ticks". I'm having some problems, my users should not be able to log more then once a day. Here is my SQL for that check:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = conn;
                        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TickLog WHERE Username = @username AND DATEPART(year, Inserted) = DATEPART(year, @date) AND DATEPART(month, Inserted) = DATEPART(month, @date) AND DATEPART(day, Inserted) = DATEPART(day, @date)";
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Now);

                        int affectedRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        if (affectedRows > 0)
                            throw new Exception("allready registered");
                    }
```

The structure of the table is very easy:

- Id, int
- Username, string
- Inserted, Date

Comment: And what's the problem with this code?

Comment: You have some kind of a solution, so what it the question then?

Comment: the solution is wrong, it does not detect if a user has already a logitem in the log on that date

Comment: That will read the entire table, consider `if exists (...) select 1 else select 0` to minimise the table scan, you can also compare the date parts with `cast(@date as date) = cast(inserted as date)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, and has a marginally better performance:

```
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = @"CASE
        WHEN EXISTS (
            SELECT
                *
            FROM
                TickLog TL
            WHERE
                TL.Username = @username
                AND TL.Inserted BETWEEN @date AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -3, @date))
            ) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END";

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Date);

    var exists = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

    if (exists != 0)
    {
        throw new Exception("already registered");
    }
}
```

Explaining:

- `EXISTS` is the best option, you don't need to fetch the whole record from the database.
- `TL.Inserted` should be a indexed column, but when you use `DATEPART` you'll not use any indexes.

For the reasoning behind using -3 milliseconds, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/167350/158074) StackOverflow answer, and [this](http://musingmarc.blogspot.com.br/2006/07/more-on-dates-and-sql.html) blog post.

Answer (score 2):

`ExecuteNonQuery()` returns the number of rows affected by an UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE.  Since you are just doing a Select, it will always return 0 affected rows.  Try using `ExecuteReader()` and checking to see if the return result has any values.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k.aspx

Alternatively, you could change your query to `SELECT COUNT(*)...` and use `ExecuteScalar()`, which will return the number of rows found (as an `Object` that you can cast to an `int`).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx